# Do I need to enforce security rules for SOQL in test methods?

Tags: apex, soql, security-review, fls, crud

I'm currently in the process of updating a managed package for security review. I've been adding the "WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED" statement to SOQL requests, however I've struggled to find any clear guidance on whether I also need to do this for SOQL requests that exist in test methods and classes. This question would extend to setup test methods too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a security review even if the SOQL queries or the dml in test method/setup run in system mode.
Of course you should have valid tests with meaningful assertion, but this is always valid.

Please note that Salesforce recommends that you enforce Field Level Security by using `WITH USER_MODE` rather than `WITH SECURITY-ENFORCED` because of these additional advantages:

- `WITH USER_MODE` takes into account polymorphic fields like `Owner` and `Task.whatId`.
- `WITH USER_MODE` processes all clauses in the SOQL `SELECT` statement including the `WHERE` clause.
- `WITH USER_MODE` finds all FLS errors in your SOQL query, while `WITH SECURITY ENFORCED` finds only the first error. Further, in user mode, you can use the `getInaccessibleFields()` method on QueryException to examine the full set of access errors.

[Enforce User Mode Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_enforce_usermode.htm)